# $touches property on Eloquent model really slows down testing

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

- Laravel Version: 7.26.1
- PHP Version: 7.4.9
- Database Driver & Version: MySql 8.0.21

#### Description:

Am I working on a project that mostly consists of `belongsTo` and `hasMany` relationships which I cache using a trick I learned a long time ago from this post [Laravel Model Caching](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-model-caching). Now the problem is when I run a test PHPUnit freezes or maybe takes to a long time to run a single test because I waited for an hour plus, but if I comment the the `$touches` property the test runs just fine. Now I cant comment out all the `$touches` property in all my models every time I want to test so my question is, what do I do, is it possible to turn it off during testing?

#### Steps To Reproduce:

Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Contracts\CacheableModelInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;

class Country extends Model implements CacheableModelInterface
{
    use Searchable,
        Concerns\HasSlug,
        Concerns\HasCache,
        Concerns\HasManyRegions,
        Concerns\HasManyProvinces,
        Concerns\HasManyLocalGovernmentAreas,
        Concerns\HasManyCities,
        Concerns\HasManyVillages;

    /**
     * The relationships that should be touched on save.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $touches = ['regions', 'provinces', 'localGovernmentAreas', 'cities', 'villages'];

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'longitude', 'latitude', 'iso_code', 'calling_code'
    ];

    /**
     * Get the indexable data array for the model.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toSearchableArray()
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
        ];
    }
}
```

Repository

```
public function getRelationshipBelongingTo(string $name, string $relationship)
{
    return ($this->model->where("name->".app()->getLocale(), $name)
                        ->firstOrFail())
                        ->{$relationship};
}
```

Controller

```
// CountryController.php
...
public function provinces(string $locale, string $name)
{
    try {
        $this->checkLocale($locale);

        app()->setLocale($locale);

        $provinces = $this->repository
            ->getRelationshipBelongingTo($name, 'cached_provinces');

        return response()->json([
            'success'       => true,
            'provinces'       => new ProvinceCollection($provinces)
        ]);

    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $exception) {

        return response()->json([
            'success'       => false,
            'message'       => "No country named '{$name}' was found in the {$this->localeFullName($locale)} database."
        ]);

    } catch (InvalidLocaleException $exception) {

        return response()->json([
            'success'       => false,
            'message'       => $exception->getMessage()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Test

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function can_return_provinces_belonging_to_country()
{
    $country = $this->createCountry();

    // Region is going to be needed in the factory when creating Province
    // files so we need to have at least one present.
    factory(\App\Region::class, 1)->create();

    $provinces = $country->provinces()->saveMany(factory(\App\Province::class, 3)->make());

    $response = $this->getJson($this->route."/{$country->name}/provinces");

    $response->assertJsonStructure([
        'success', 'provinces'
    ]);

    $responseProvinces = $response->json('provinces');

    $this->assertEquals($provinces->count(), collect($responseProvinces)->count());

    $response->assertOk();
}
```

Comment: and do all these other models also have 'touches' defined?

Comment: Yes they all do, not exactly the same but relative to their relationships.

Comment: I know its possible to disable $touches with `Model::withoutTouching()`  but is it possible when using factories to generate dummy data?

Comment: yea not sure about that, looking to see if an infinite loop might be happening, if a parent and child are setup to touch each others timestamps but not sure about that

Comment: I just noticed that the slowness also occurs when I run `artisan db:seed` so it's definitely occurring in the factories. It is trying to perform the `touch` everytime a new resource is created, this is not very useful when creating a lot of dummy data. I just want to turn it off when running PHPUnit test or running in console.